# Empty all cells from UICollectionView

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

Using iOS6's awesome new `UICollectionView` how am I able to delete all of the `UICollectionViewCell` objects in a big loop?

Say I've loaded all my data into it already, I hit refresh, I want to delete everything currently in there, then just call my stuff again.

I've found `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` which takes an `NSArray`, so how can I get all items into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I can use `deleteSections` and pass a `NSIndexSet` through to it, making a range of `0,0` and it'll delete the one and only section.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
[self.collectionView deleteSections:indexSet];
```

I could probably just use `indexSetWithIndex` but when I did my app crashed.

Comment: why indexSetWithIndex:0 crashes? I encounter this and don't know why

Answer (score 4):

The proper way of clearing out a UICollectionVew is to simply clear the data source and then reload the collection view.

So if your data source was an array:

```
self.dataArray = nil;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Boom, you're cleared out.

Comment: BOOM, crash, in my case.

Comment: probably want to do: `self.dataArray = []` oppose to `nil` to prevent crash